# What does "headline" mean in a job application form?

Tags: meaning

I was applying for an internship online and one of fields I had to fill after the name field was "headline". What does headline mean in this specific context?

Here's a screenshot of the form.
[image: photo of the form]

I can guess they mean address, but I'm not sure. Can someone please tell me? 
And thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not address.

I *think* they are looking for a brief description of you / your skills such as would [appear on your CV / resume](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/how-to-write-a-resume-headline-2061036). For example:

> An engineering graduate with great communication skills

This seems to be common terminology in the US. I haven't seen it in the UK before (but I haven't applied for a job for many years!)

If you Google **resume headline** you will find plenty of examples and tips.